# How to add UIView on top of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, addsubview

I have a table in my viewController class

On tapping of a button (this button is outside of table), i wanted to show some **UIView on top of tableView alone** and a web service request is sent. After receiving the response, i want to remove the UIView which i have added.

`tableView.addSubview(myview)` didn't work for me, but `self.view.addSubview(myview)` worked but i wanted to overlay my UIView only on top of table view.

My question is specific to how to add/remove subview to a tableview. How can i achieve this?

Comment: you can add that view as tableview's header view .

Comment: self.tableView.tableHeaderView = myview;

Comment: I don't think they are looking for a header view as this would not be on top of the table. Just the small section at the start.

Comment: @Greg while sending a webrequest he/she can show hide the view as a  subview of header view .Or he/she has to add subview in self.view and bringSubViewToFront might be required.

Comment: just add code [self.view bringSubViewToFront: YourView] after adding "YourView" on your main view.

Answer (score 15):

Try like this for adding header on top

```
let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: XXX, y: YYY, width: XXX, height: YYY))
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: XXX, y: YYY, width: XXX, height: YYY))
headerView.addSubview(imageView)
let labelView = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: XXX, y: YYY, width: XXX, height: YYY))
headerView.addSubview(labelView)
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
```

It'll add header on UITableView

Comment: @ixany Welcome ... :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a `UINavigationController` with the table as one of it's view controllers, I have found the easiest way is to insert it here directly above the `UITableView`. This code could be called in your UITableViewController when you tap the button to display the view:

```
 [self.navigationController.view addSubview:<your UIView>];
```